# Can't disable selection on iPhone using jquery

Tags: jquery, ios

I'm trying to get the following code that is simply two buttons that run two different scripts.  when the first button is pressed, the 2nd button becomes enabled.  The 2nd button has to be held down for 10 seconds while a counter counts down before the 2nd script is activated.  this works well on my laptop, but I need to get it to work on my iPhone.  When I try to hold down the 2nd button, the text selection comes up.  pushing the 2nd button once and letting go will cause the countdown to execute automatically, but I only want the countdown to happen while the button is being depressed.

I tried this CSS `-webkit-user-select: none;` but I couldn't get it to work unless I was doing it incorrectly.  I would like to apply this to the entire document.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var countDownSecs = 10;
var check = null;

function printCountDown() {
    if (check == null && document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML != 'Launched!') {
        var cnt = countDownSecs;
            check = setInterval(function () {
                cnt -= 1;
                document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = cnt;
                if (cnt == 0) {
                launch();
                  }
            }, 1000);
    }
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(check);
    check = null;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = countDownSecs;
}

function launch() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cgi-bin/launch.cgi"
        })
    clearInterval(check);
    check = null;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = 'Launched!';
}

    function ckcont() {
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "cgi-bin/ckcont.cgi"
                    })
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="continuity">Check Continuity</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#continuity").click(function(){
$("p").toggleClass("main");
$("#launch").removeAttr("disabled");
ckcont();
  });
});
</script>

<button id="launch" disabled="disabled">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Count Down:&nbsp;
<span id="counter"><script>document.write(countDownSecs);</script></span>
</button>

<script>
$("#launch").bind( "mousedown touchstart", function() {
if (check != null){
    stop();
}
//$( "body" ).append( "<span style='color:#f00;'>Mouse up.</span><br>" );
});

$("#launch").bind( "mouseup touchend", function() {
printCountDown();
//$( "body" ).append( "<span style='color:#00f;'>Mouse down.</span><br>" );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

Comment: I will try that, thanks.  Can you help me with where to put the code so it applies to the entire document?  I'm new to web development.

Comment: *{-webkit-touch-callout: none;}
put this to your css file or css section un html. If you use asterix(*) the property is applied to all elements.